# How to check all checkboxes checked or not in a panel in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i added checkboxes dynamically to panel.

```
for (int intControlIndex = 0; intControlIndex < dsTagsList.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intControlIndex++)
{
   chkList1 = new CheckBox();
   chkList1.Text = dsTagsList.Tables[0].Rows[intControlIndex][0].ToString();
   chkList1.ID = "Chk" + intControlIndex;
   chkList1.Font.Name = "Verdana";
   chkList1.Height = 20;
   chkList1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
   chkList1.Font.Size = 10;
   panelTags.Controls.Add(chkList1);
   panelTags.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
}
```

How to check which checkboxes selected or not ?
Please tell me....

Comment: do you mean on a button click?  Just re loop through the rows and check if the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would loop through all controls in the panel, check if the control is a check box, then act on it if it is.

```
foreach(Control child in panelTags.Controls)
{
    if(!(child is CheckBox))
        continue;

    if((child as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        // Do 'is checked' something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do 'is not checked' something
    }
}
```

Or better yet, using LINQ `OfType` that filters an enumerable by type:

```
foreach(CheckBox child in panelTags.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if(child.Checked)
    {
        // Do 'is checked' something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do 'is not checked' something
    }
}
```

The LINQ statement lets us further query the list.
If you only want to act on checked checkboxes.

```
// Add to Usings
using System.Linq;

foreach(CheckBox child in panelTags.Controls
                              .OfType<CheckBox>()
                              .Where(chk => chk.Checked))
{
    // Do 'is checked' something
}
```

A few other things I can think of that may be causing problems:

1. Is the `foreach` is being called before `Page_Load`?  Since you're likely running this in a postback, the `Page_Load` is when [the control properties are loaded with information recovered from view state and control state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).
2. Is the checkbox creation within a `if(!IsPostBack)` to prevent multiple controls from being added?
3. Are you calling `panelTags.Controls.Clear();` before adding the checkboxes this will remove any data returned from the page>

Comment: Hi David,i am trying above code but it does not goes to the following line if i selected the checkboxes.if((child as CheckBox).Checked)

Comment: for linq to sql statement getting error at  oftype.saying system.web.ui.controls does not contain oftype missing assembly reference like that....

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;`  I also noticed an issue with the setting of the checkboxes (see above)

Comment: i tried the link to sql code not going to foreach loop if i selecting the checkboxes.please help me out what was wrong...?

Comment: When you debug, does the `panelTags.Controls` have any items?

Comment: i am calling checkbox creation with in if(!isPostback) that was the issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
void ReadCheckBoxControls(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (child.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox") && child.ID.IndexOf("Chk") == 0)
            {
                CheckBox CB = (CheckBox)child;
                if (CB.Checked == true) { 
                 // Your code here
                }
                else {
                 // Your code here
                }
            }
            if (child.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                ReadCheckBoxControls(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call this method like this:

```
ReadCheckBoxControls(this.panelTags);
```

I hope this can help you, good luck.

Comment: why my code was not going to this line if (CB.Checked == true) if i selected the checkboxes in panel..please tell me...

Comment: Call the method with: ReadCheckBoxControls(this.panelTags); it will search the child controls you added in the code-behind. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the controls you added dynamically lost their existence so you had to  redefine
them..either on page pre_int of page_load

than you can do this..

```
 for (int intControlIndex = 0; intControlIndex < dsTagsList.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intControlIndex++)
    {
      CheckBox chkList1 = (CheckBox)panelTags.findcontrol("Chk" + intControlIndex);

      if(chkList1 != null)
        {
           if(chkList1.checked)
             {
               do something..
             }
        }
    }
```

for sample see this..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
            AddCheckBoxes();
    }

    public void AddCheckBoxes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();
            chkbox.ID = "chk" + i.ToString();
            chkbox.Text = "check box " + i.ToString();               
            pan.Controls.Add(chkbox);
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)pan.FindControl("chk" + i.ToString());            
            if(chkbox.Checked)
                lblselected.Text += "check box " + i.ToString() +" ; ";

        }
    }
```

and Html is

```
 <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pan" runat="server">

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Show selected" onclick="btn_Click" />

    Selected : <asp:Label ID="lblselected" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```